# How to get a value from a lists of array and use it in a v-if to display in VUEJS

Tags: html, vue.js

I am trying to get a value from the lists of array from the api and use a v-if to display in the view page.

For example:

I have the response from api like this upon doing console:

```
list: [ "user:getAll",..................................................,  __ob__: Observer]
```

Now i want to display some text in a box, i am displaying using like this:

```
  <div>
    <div v-if="!list === 'place:list'">
      Do not show
    </div>
  <div v-else>Show</div>
  </div>
```

Issue is v-if is not working i guess as it is not getting the `place:list`

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing an array to a string. I'm guessing what you mean to do is check if the string 'place:list' is in the list array?

```
<div>
    <div v-if="!list.includes('place:list')">
      Do not show
    </div>
  <div v-else>Show</div>
  </div>
```